# C# need explanation on new constraint (new T(...))

Tags: c#, class, generics, constraints, new-operator

The following Code returns an error:

```
private void HandleBookLogic<T>() where T : Book , new()
{
    LibraryList.Items.Add(new MyItems(new T(int.Parse(copyNumber.Text), 
                                        itemName.Text, 
                                        DateTime.Parse(TimePrinted.Text), 
                                        int.Parse(Guid.Text), 
                                        (JournalCategory)Enum.Parse(typeof(JournalCategory), 
                                        Category.Text))));
}
```

> 'T' cannot provide arguements when creating an instance of Variable
>   Type

I have 3 classes with generic usage: `reading\cooking\science`

`MyItems` is the class that responsible for the XAML bindings to the `ListView` (doesn't matter right now). Each one of the 3 classes gives me an error as well:

> 'Reading' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless
>   constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or
>   method 'ItemWindow.HandleBookLogic()

I'm very fresh to C#, I kind of "understand" the errors but do not know how to handle them.

Appreciate the help.

**EDIT**: Extra code:

```
private void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    if (Type.Text == "Journal")
    {
        HandleJournalLogic();
    }
    else
    {
        if (Type.Text == "Reading")
            HandleBookLogic<Reading>();
        else if (Type.Text == "Cooking")
            HandleBookLogic<Cooking>();
        else
        {
            HandleBookLogic<Science>();
        }
    }
    InitFields();
}
```

Can someone fix my code so I can learn of it?

Comment: While it is easy for an experienced programmer to see that it is probably not the best solution, it is harder to suggest best solution as it really depends on what you do as a whole...

Answer (score 3):

The `new`  constraint is only for a parameterless constructor. If you need a constructor that takes arguments then your caller needs to tell you how to construct instances. One common approach is for your method to take a factory delegate as an argument.

For example, you could take a `Func<int, T>` for a constructor that takes an `int`; the caller can supply the function using a lambda.

If you know the exact constructor signature you could also use reflection or else `dynamic`. Those options will both be a lot slower than passing a delegate, though. Depending on your needs that may not be a problem.

Comment: Is this the only way? I will update my post with some more code so you could guide me. thx mate.

Comment: From your code example, I actually think the best solution would be to use normal subtype polymorphism to dispatch to the different implementations. That is: rather than switching on a string representing which "type" of operation you need to do, just use *actual types* for the different operations.

Comment: Since I'm new to C# and I've learned the concept of delegates a few days ago, I would love to see a solution via delegate.